# Search Crawl - Access Denied

Tags: search, crawling

Search crawl log Error: 
"Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access Account has access to this repository, or add a crawl rule to crawl this repository. If the repository being crawled is a SharePoint repository, verify that the account you are using has "Full Read" permissions on the SharePoint Web Application being crawled."

I've checked the search account and everything seems to be correct.

- Search Admin Web Service  domain\sp_search
- Search Query Web Service  domain\sp_search
- Web Applications User Policy domain\sp_search set to 'Full Read'

This is a clean installation with SP1 installed. 
Have I missed anything?

Hope you can help.

[image: Policy for Web Application]

Comment: Is the web application it's trying to crawl set with integrated authentication?

Comment: Please give us details of the content source that is giving the error.

Comment: Hi. It fails to crawl MySite and our Default web application (Content Source: Local SharePoint Sites). The error message I get is detailed above.

Comment: To PirateEric: I believe so. How can I confirm this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you are running into a loopback authentication issue. This will happen if content is accessed from a server to the same server using an alternate DNS name. For example:

1. Server name: srvSP2010wfe
2. Portal URL pointing to server (1.): http://portal
3. DNS config: portal A IP.OF.Server.1

The resolution is described here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

The article is mentioning two methods:

**Method 1** is setting the Key to disable the LoopBackCheck in general. This is considered less secure, but in real life it is easier during debugging the problem.
Maybe you can disable it and if the solution works i would suggest to use the back connections host method to fix the problem.

**Method 2** is setting a multi-string value. The string must contain all url's + FQDN (portal and portal.domain.local) that are not the machines hostname. Using this method is more secure because only selected url's are excluded from the loopback check. During debugging in a complicated setup this is harder to get right if you hit this for the first time.

After configuring the needed method to successfully run through the loopback check the index on the local machine should be able to access the content if the content access account has the needed privileges.

More info's on configuring the default access account are here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261796.aspx

Comment: Marco you're a genius. I disbaled the loopback and kicked off the crawl. I would be grateful if you could elaborate on the 'back connections host method'. Thanks again.

Comment: I've edited my post to get you some more information about the issue. Thanx for the genius ;-)

Comment: I 2nd the Genius nomination. Marco thank you for the clear explanation and solution to my issue after I enabled https on our SharePoint MOSS 2007 server.

Comment: Agree, this is genius - can't tell you how much time this saved. Also works in 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go to the search administration page and explicitly set the default crawl account. It is a link in the System Status area, and if you follow it you can enter the account and password. Do this even if you already have the correct account name. I have found it doesn't always work unless you set it here, possibly because it is not picking up the password.

Comment: Hi. No luck with this solution either. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is one time I've had this error when I knew that the content access account had the appropriate permissions. That is when I have created a web application and only created site collections in managed paths and nothing at the top level. For example, we created a web application: portal.mycompany.com and then created the site collections of portal.mycompany.com/teams/team1, portal.mycompany.com/teams/team2 but we did not create a site collection at portal.mycompany.com because we were not ready to start putting content at that level. However, we still wanted to search the contents from the other site collections. I always got this error. The search engine will start at the top level of web applications, and that is what is entered in the default "Local SharePoint Sites" content source. However, you will want to manually enter the other site collections in this content source since you cannot crawl anything at that top level. I don't know if this is the exact issue you are facing, but it was definitely the root of my problem and this error was what was displayed instead of something indicating that there was no content to be crawled.

Comment: Thanks Lori. No luck with this solution. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still getting access denied error after Disabling loopback check, make sure that you have given the Default Content Access account "Retrieve People Data for Search Crawlers" permissions. (From Manage Service Applications Page, select UserProfile Service Application and click on Administrators to view this setting)

Answer (score 0):

To access the web app while crawling, you need the following to be setup:

- the default zone is always crawled
- ntlm authentication is used.

Comment: Where exactly os the zone & security NTLM configured within the search admin? The farm is currently NTLM, I plan to configure kerberos at a later date. Thanks

Comment: you don't configure NTLM & zone access in the search admin. That's configured in the web app settings.

Comment: Hi Bas. The default zone is set with Full Read permissions.

Comment: Full read permissions for the default access account too?

Answer (score 0):

In our environment we are using a netscaler. This caused an authentication issue with the crawl account. I added an entry in the host file on the SharePoint servers and this fixed the issue.

Comment: What entry did you add in the host file? We have netscaler and the same issue with sharepoint search.